# Does NEC 2023 require conduit mounting hardware to be listed?

Tags: electrical, conduit, nec, emt

I only have the NEC 2020 edition on hand, but from what I'm reading on 358.6 for EMT listing requirements:

> EMT, factory elbows, and associated fittings shall be listed

I think it's safe to assume parts around supporting the conduit do not need to be UL or some other form of listed? My concern is listing requirements for support hardware are covered by some other part of the code book, or even another code entirely.
A few examples of parts I'm looking at that are not UL listed.

- Threaded rod
- Threaded rod conduit support
- Threaded rod mount plates
- Strut hardware
- Custom hardware for supporting EMT in place

Some of the hardware mentioned I have found UL listings for, but not all of it. For example, McMaster-Carr catalog has some parts I can use, but without any listings.

Comment: Seems like a really good question. Sounds like a firefighter's equipment type issue: Pick up 1/4-20 all-thread at Lowes for $1/foot. Pick up _UL-listed_ 1/4-20 all-thread at the electrical supply house for $10.58/foot...

Comment: Pretty sure it follows a logical sequence. *i.e.* the conduit clamp is listed for the purpose, the screw holding it to the wall is just a screw, etc. but will await one of the folks in that side of the trade.